# SQL SERVER: Why the removal of hypen can make one table column show up or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server

enter image description here

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

In image 1, with the highlighted hypens, the SubDescn column in image 2 cannot show up;
however, after removing the hypens, the SubDescn column shows up.

Can someone help explain the reason? and the syntax of this usage? Many thanks!

Comment: These are [comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181627.aspx).

Comment: `--` Indicates user-provided text or comments

Answer (score 4):

`--` Are used for [comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181627.aspx).

They are most commonly used to write notes on codes, so it will be easier to maintain the code. Consider a very large an confusing Procedure, no one will be able to understand it, but as the writer of this code, you can add comments on every part to make it more clear.

For example:

```
-- Update the target will default values
UPDATE Targ_Tab t
SET t.col = -1,
    t.col2 = '-1' 
....

--Insert new records
INSERT INTO .....
```

You can also use `/* .... */` for [blocks of comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178623.aspx)(more then 1 row)

```
/* Bla bla bla....
 Bla bla bla */
```

Answer (score 0):

-- is used for comments in sql.

for example :

```
  -- Choose the AdventureWorks2012 database.  
    USE AdventureWorks2012;  
     GO  
  -- Choose all columns and all rows from the Address table.  
  SELECT *  
   FROM Person.Address  
   ORDER BY PostalCode ASC; -- We do not have to specify ASC because   
   -- that is the default.  
    GO
```

you can use short cuts for this :

```
     Make the selected text a comment   CTRL+K, CTRL+C
     Uncomment the selected text    CTRL+K, CTRL+U
```